# Torque rating of 8F35 and 8F57 transmissions

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, torque-converter

What is the maximum torque those Ford transmissions can handle?

Bonus question: new 7-speed auto in a Ford Focus ST mk4 is based on one of those two with a 2nd gear removed. Does it keep the torque rating?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the 8F35 is 260 lb-ft. No clue on the 8F57.

Comment: @Paulster2 that's 352Nm and Focus ST with 420Nm shouldn't have it. That probably implies that the gearbox in question should be based on a stronger 8F57, which in some applications handles 480-515Nm.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](https://www.transmissiondigest.com/ford-motor-company-and-the-hat-trick/), there are three transmissions which share the "8Fxx" monicker:

```
 8F24 - 240nm input torque
 8F35 - 350nm input torque
 8F57 - 575nm input torque
```

All three of these are eight speed transmissions. They were co-developed between Ford and GM as a joint venture in the hopes of finding design and manufacturing efficiencies between the two companies.

As far as removing 2nd gear in the transmission, according to [this source](https://fordauthority.com/2021/02/2021-ford-edge-st-gains-new-7-speed-automatic-transmission-exclusive/), they didn't physically remove anything. The transmission is exactly the same, they *programmatically* removed 2nd gear. This means, they reprogrammed the transmission to skip 2nd gear. This decision was based on customer feedback. Due to this, the transmission would have the same torque input rating.

The gear ratios are as follows:

```
 Gear Ratios                2021 Ford Edge ST               2020 Ford Edge ST
 1st                        4.48                            4.48
 2nd                        2.87                            3.15
 3rd                        1.84                            2.87
 4th                        1.41                            1.84
 5th                        1.0                             1.41
 6th                        0.74                            1.0
 7th                        0.62                            0.74
 8th                        N/A                             0.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing a gear will not change the torque rating. It will change how the engine power is delivered to the road.

The rating is based on the strength of the case, the design of the teeth etc. If you exceed the torque limit then gears can be stripped or cases split or burst so when tuning engines that gearbox torque limit should be checked.

Comment: The problem with that is speculation. People on the internet said 'removed a gear'. I personally don't know and haven't found if there are more changes, don't know the model, anything.

Comment: Well I have seen and had to change gearboxes due to damage from too much power : torque went up by a factor of 3 and power by a factor of 2 so I was not speculating...

Comment: No, I meant myself. In my question i said a simple '2nd gear removed', while it can actually be that half of the gearbox is different.

Comment: Mike, is experienced, and educated in what he answers. Removing a gear, will not slow the power output. Revolution speed is retained within the transmission. Either get the correct transmission paired, or tweak the transmission software to downgraded torque curve. I know one person who specialises in Mercedesbenz acquired ZF transmission boxes, he goes by the name of BenzNinja, and helped me stay under 700 nm.